# Hadoop Streaming - Too many map tasks

Tags: hadoop

I realize that we can't exactly dictate how many map tasks to use, we can only suggest. But still it doesn't make sense.

```
2016-01-07 07:19:25,117 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat (main): Total input paths to process : 1
2016-01-07 07:19:25,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): number of splits:40
```

I have a single `.txt` file in my input which contains:

```
x,2,65
t,6,12
y,5,11
n,3,71
.
.
(8 lines)
```

I would expect 8 map tasks to be created, but instead I get 40 map tasks, from which 32 have nothing coming through stdin and hence don't do anything.

I'm running a separate executable through each map task with each line containing the parameters needed.

How does this all work?

Comment: Can you paste the command you are using?

Comment: @user1265125: Have a look at how hadoop streaming works : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#How_Streaming_Works